# Getting odd output from Blackjack sim

Tags: python

Slowly working on Blackjack simulator with a cli.  I just started on it so I'm not too deep into it, but I'm already getting odd outputs: sometimes when I run the code below, it gives me a normal output (like `4 of Clubs, 9 of Spades`) but sometimes it's giving me output like `c of Diamonds` or `i of Clubs`.  Since I don't have anything set to `c` or `i` defined in the `Card` function, I can't figure out why it'd be giving me that sort of output.  Can anyone explain this to me?

```
import random

def Card():
    cardValue = random.randint(2,10)
    suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
    special = ['Ace', 'King', 'Queen', 'Jack']
    special = random.choice(special)
    suit = random.choice(suits)
    special = random.choice(special)
    randO = random.randint(1,52)
    if randO > 16:
        print(cardValue,'of',suit)
    else:
        if special == 'Ace':
            cardValue = 11
            print(special,'of',suit)
        else:
            cardValue = 10
            print(special,'of',suit)

Card()
Card()
```

Comment: This is not a good way to go about random sampling.  It doesn't adjust for cards that have already bee removed from the deck.  You should make a deck of 52 cards, perhaps (rank, suit) tuples, and draw (and remove) random cards from the deck.  Otherwise, you'll sooner or later end up with the Ace of Spades in two different hands, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, much appreciated - I had indeed run into the Ace of Spades * 2 problem.

Comment: You can also random.shuffle on a list returned by range(1, 53), and then take the cards in order, since the deck has been "shuffled".

Comment: The "c" is from "clubs" and is the result of the 2nd special = random.choice(special) statement, since the first random.choice returns "clubs", the second returns some letter from "clubs".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `special` too often.

```
special = ['Ace', 'King', 'Queen', 'Jack']
```

Right now, special is a list.

```
special = random.choice(special)
```

Now it's either "Ace" or "King" or "Queen" or "Jack".

```
suit = random.choice(suits)
special = random.choice(special)
```

And now when you execute this line again, it means "choose a random character from whatever word `special` is".

Give `special` a better name -- don't use it to mean both a list and a word -- and you don't need to call `random.choice(special)` twice.